# border-radius and overflow (on hover) in Chrome/Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, overflow

I have a problem with Chrome & Opera. I'm using border-radius to create "circle divs" and I want to display some text inside of this div on hover.

In Firefox and IE everythings working fine. But when the element (article) is hovered in Chrome/Opera the overflow is visible for one second. When I remove the cursor from the element the overflow is visible again (for one second). You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52bfj.jpg). It should look like the third image.

```html
<article>
    <a href="/">
        <div class="info">
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <img class="sw" src="images/image-sw.jpg">
        <img class="clr" src="images/image-colour.jpg">
    </a>
</article>
```

CSS:

```css
article{
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
border-radius: 180px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
background: #e3e3e3;
padding: 5px;
}

.info{
position: absolute;
background: #222222;
color: #ffffff;
height: 80px;
width: 300px;
top: 320px;
padding: 10px 0;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2;
overflow: hidden;
}

article:hover .info {
top: 240px;
}

article img{
border-radius: 180px;
position: absolute;
left: 5px;
top: 5px;
display: block;
}

article .clr{
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
z-index: 1;
}

article:hover .clr{
opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;` from `article .clr`. Your are seeing the `transition` take `0.2s` that is why you are seeing that flash in chrome. You can read more about the transition property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).